# Jmeter - Error " Empty Test Plan " thrown while trying to open Jmeter script copied from another machine

Tags: apache, jmeter

when I'm trying to open the JMeter script which was copied from another server, im getting below error with a dialog box - Empty Test Plan.
My Machine : 
Java Version:1.8.0_72
and apache-jmeter-2.11

Another server from where scripts are copied:
Java version is : 1.8.0_45
and apache-jmeter-2.13

```
2016/03/14 07:35:47 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\XXX Perf Tests\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\tests\stressICXXX.jmx 
2016/03/14 07:35:47 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\XXX Perf Tests\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\tests' 
2016/03/14 07:35:49 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1
---- Debugging information ----
message             : -1
cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
cause-message       : -1
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[3]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
line number         : 120481
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
------------------------------- : -1 : -1
---- Debugging information ----
message             : -1
cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
cause-message       : -1
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[3]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
line number         : 120481
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
message             : -1 : -1
---- Debugging information ----
message             : -1
cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
cause-message       : -1
class               : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[3]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
line number         : 120481
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController
converter-type[1]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : -1 : -1
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FloatProperty
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[3]/ThroughputController/FloatProperty/name
line number         : 120481
version             : 2.11 r1554548
------------------------------- 
2016/03/14 07:35:49 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: try to install jmeter 2.13 on your machine. Could be that ThroughputController objects are not backward compatible.

Comment: Thanks Kiril S. for the quick response. I would try to install 2.13. But before upgrading , i have two applications which are running good on this 2.11 JMeter version in my controller . My question is : If i upgrade , will those two apps work same without any issues ?

Comment: You don't have to uninstall your old version, just get jmeter 2.13 zip, unzip it in some folder and run for this test. If script doesn't work there either you should look at other possible differences: are you transferring script from linux to windows (or vice versa)? do you have any plug-ins? etc

Comment: Sometimes, the missing plugin causes the same issue. Please ensure that /lib/ext has the needed extra jars

Comment: Thanks Kiril S. and ViaSat for the solutions. As Kiril S. mentioned i have installed 2.13 in another folder and ran the test plan , it worked. :)